# Is there any function that is not continuous on it entire domain?

Tags: calculus, continuity

Is there any function that is not continuous on it entire domain?

Comment: Do you mean that the function is not continuous at any point? If so, then I think $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ will do the trick.

Comment: @mpw What would you call that function? "chi q"? Or is there another name for that. Now I am curious about that function.

Comment: It is called the characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$, presumably defined on the real numbers to be 1 if $x$ is rational, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @Asimov: $\mathbb Q$ is the set of rational real numbers (real numbers that can be expressed as a ratio of integers, like $2/3$ or $-17/1$). Each subset $S$ of the real numbers gives rise to a function $\chi_S$ called the "characteristic function of $S$", defined as $$\chi_S(x) = \begin{cases}1,&\textrm{ if }x \in S\\0, &\textrm{ if }x \notin S\end{cases}$$ This function tells whether or not a specified number $x$  belongs to the set $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looking for a function on $\mathbb R$ that is not continuous at any point, consider $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb Q$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: In "$x\in \mathbb Q$" what is $\mathbb Q$ I have never seen this notation $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @theASHAS $\mathbb{Q}$ signifies the set of all rational numbers, and Ittay just handed you the Dirichlet function, which is continuous nowhere on its entire domain.

Comment: @theASHAS This is the function $f$ where $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is rational, and $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is irrational.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps less useful than the Dirichlet function, but the [empty function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function) is also discontinuous at every point in its domain—perhaps noteworthy in that it is also continuous at every point in its domain.

Such an unintuitive result is called a [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).